# C#: Declaring a local variable after null check

Tags: c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching

Is and As can assign local variable to be used subsequently.

Is there a similar way to declare a local variable to be used after a null check?

```
if(Factory() != null factoryResult)
{
  factoryResult.UsingResult();
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting from this? It doesn't make sense to me. There is nothing assigned here and no pattern matched.

Comment: What's wrong with still using `is`?

Comment: ^^ `if( Factory() is Product product ) product.UsingResult();` <- like that?

Comment: You can still use `is`. check this example out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811614/c-sharp-is-keyword-and-checking-for-not

Comment: @Fildor Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: The question's own link shows the answer. `if (iBoxed is int a)` defines a new variable whose value isn't null. The docs call this a [declaration pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns). You can use `if(Factory() is SomeType x)`

Comment: Maybe you are confused, because `null is SomeType` is false => https://dotnetfiddle.net/aJM5I5

Comment: If the ONLY thing your are doing with `factoryResult` is what you posted, then you could just write: `Factory()?.UsingResult();`

Comment: Why don't you just use ```Factory()?.UsingResult()```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which version of `c#` you're using, it is possible to use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns) using `is` keyword (`is not`, if you want the opposite of what has been stated) to check not only for `null` but also for specific properties, and declare in one go. You could also use the declared variable for additional checks in the same `if` statement

As per your example, `{ }` would mean that it's an object of a class that is not null:

```
if(Factory() is { } factoryResult)
{
  factoryResult.UsingResult();
}
```

or

```
if(Factory() is FactoryResult factoryResult)
{
  factoryResult.UsingResult();
}
```

assuming that `FactoryResult` is a class that is being returned from `Factory()`

or suppose you have to check also for `IsUsable` `boolean` that has to be true at the same time:

```
if(Factory() is FactoryResult { IsUsable: true } factoryResult)
{
  factoryResult.UsingResult();
}
```